# Mount glass shower wall with adhesive to avoid drilling holes in the bathroom tiles

Tags: walls, shower, adhesive, glass

I would like to mount a glass shower wall in the bathroom but avoid having to drill holes.
The model in question is the following: http://www.bathdeluxe.com/products/130/130-328-toscana-wall-manual.pdf
As you can see it requires 4 screws to affix it but I would prefer to use an adhesive if there is anything that can be used in this situation.

I've been looking on different other somewhat similar questions and some of the suggestions were: Kerdi-Fix / Plumbers Goop. Since I have never used any of these I would like to ask if either of these are good for this purpose or if there is any other known method to achieve what I desire.

LE: I have stumbled upon an adhesive that seems to be very powerful but I would love to get a second opinion on it so I am linking to the product sheet: http://www.bostik.se/downloads/datasheet.ashx?p=P0703&l=EN

Regards, 
Ovi

Since the answer was requested in other comments to be added to the initial post, the solution that was sent by the manufacturer and actually fits my requirement is a special "Glue kit" they sell for exactly this type of requests. The product was linked in another comment in case anyone is looking for something like this (there is no term I could use that people could just search for and find the right thing)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. Even if you use a perfect glue, you put all that stress on your tiles and their attachment to the wall. They are not designed to handle this kind of load. This glass wall needs to be attached to the wood framing inside the wall (or directly to concrete wall if your walls are concrete).

Comment: Are you trying to avoid damaging the tiles? Using an adhesive strong enough to hold that is never going to come off so the tiles will be damaged anyway. Depending on your tile, you could drill the grout lines and if you remove the door later the grout could be patched. If you do drill the tiles, start with the drill set on "drill only" NOT hammer. Once you are through the tile you can use the hammer setting if you are driling concrete.

Comment: First of all I want to avoid drilling holes because it would mean I need to buy a special drill head for this and because my brother (who owns the apartment) does not want to risk breaking the tile so he wanted me to find this type of solution. He is ok with not being able to remove this later on without removing the tiles, he is more interested in not risking having a broken tile that would require a lot more work to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers guys but I actually asked the manufacturer if they have any suggestions and they came with the best solution ever :D

Apparently there is [a kit available](https://media1.bauhaus.se/media/pdf/3000508B.pdf). I am not sure how one would search for this as the manufacturer sells this "glue kit" especially for this type of situations. I am not sure if this is something you can find anywhere but for reference [here is the actual product](https://www.bauhaus.se/limkit-camargue-skargard-borrfri-montering-av-duschprofiler.html).

I have not mounted it yet but once it arrives and I do the work I will try to provide more details about it.

Comment: This is the answer to my problem. This is exactly what I am going to do and it's what I was actually looking for so why does it not answer the question?
I can of course edit the initial post but then it would not be a question anymore as much as a solution from the start.

LE: I added the info int he initial comment as well

Comment: @isherwood Please explain why you think this is not an answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never considered mounting a glass shower "wall" (not a door) without using screws. However, what you are proposing is probably the best idea, especially if there isn't solid wood or concrete for a backer to anchor the screws to.

The adhesive is waterproof and appears to be strong enough to hold the frame to the wall (tiles). The glass wall is designed to sit on the floor, so all the weight of the glass is taken by the floor not the glue. (Sometimes we worry about "creep" if something is not mechanically fastened. )

I wouldn't use it for a door installation, but I think it'll be fine for the glass wall. By the way, I'd practice applying the adhesive before you do the final install. I'd also mask off the adjacent tiles. If it gets  where you don't want it, it's difficult to remove.

Comment: Yes, a good adhesive would hold the glass wall securely to the tiles. But then the tiles might detach from the underlying wall.

Comment: Anything is possible, I guess. But for the tiles to "come loose" and fail, the glass wall will need to move "away" from the wall or twist off the wall. It can't move away from the wall because it's anchored (mastic) to the floor and it can't twist off the wall unless someone twists the glass...If that happens, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: I did purchase a "shower wall holder" to use and provide more support but I would expect the tiles to hold the weight even without it but maybe I am being unreasonable.